# How can I set data createContext?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-context

How can I set data into the state?

And how can I solve `createContext` error?

```js
export const LastChanceContext = createContext() //in there return error: Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.

export const GET_LASTCHANCE = "GET_LASTCHANCE"


const LastChanceWrapper = ({children} : {children:any}) => {

    const initialState = {
        lastChances: [],
        lastChance: {}
    };
    console.log('asd',initialState);

    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(lastChanceReducer, initialState);

    useEffect(() => {
        const getLastChance = async () => {
            const result = await axiosFetch('http://65.21.148.176:2803/api/Home/Get');
            const action = {
                type:GET_LASTCHANCE,
                payload:result.data.data.lastChanceList
            };
            if(Object.keys(result).length !== 0) {
                 dispatch(
                     {state,
                    action}
                 )

                console.log(result.data.data.lastChanceList);
            }

        };

        getLastChance();
    }, [])


    return (
        <LastChanceContext.Provider value={{
            lastChances: state.lastChances,
            lastChance: state.lastChance
        }}>
            {children}
        </LastChanceContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default LastChanceWrapper
```

Comment: For the error you're getting, `createContext` needs to be passed an initial value param, for example `createContext({ lastChances: [], lastChance: {} })`.

Comment: Regarding the other question, what do you mean by _"How can I set data into the state"_? Is it the case that you want to set data into state in the consumers of the context? If so, then you need to expose the state setter (`dispatch`) in the context provider value.